# SSIS : Creating a flat file with different row formats

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, bids

I want to create a flat file output, where format of rows is different. 
file has header, middle data rows, footer row.
file will look Like below

```
H|deptcode123|deptNameXYZ|totalemp300   
E|Sam|Johnson|address1|empCode1|........many other columns
E|Sam2|Johnson2|address2|empCode2|........many other columns
E|Sam4|Johnson3|address3|empCode3|........many other columns
E|Sam5|Johnson4|address4|empCode4|........many other columns         
J|300|250000
```

How can I generate this file in SSIS. Input will come from different tables, I am planning to write 3 separate queries/ sp's to get the header, middle row and footer row record.

Comment: Is the header just a the start, or do you have multiple groups of headers, detail, footers appearing? If you have multiple groups of H/D/F then you need to basically build it in a SQL statement. The two solutions below don't cater for headers reappearing in the middle

Comment: Header(H) as well as footer(F) will appear just once in a file, middle rows(D) will be multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

To do this you need a data flow and connection manager for each different type of rowset. For example to have different header, body, and footer you would need 3 dataflows and 3 flat file connection managers. Each flat file connection manager points to the same file. The trick is to make sure the setting `Overwrite data in the file` in the Flat File destination is unchecked. This way each data flow executes and appends to the file and each data flow can have its discrete columns and data types.

[image] [image]

Comment: I tried this, but the number of columns in each type is different. Header(H) has suppose 5 column as middle rows(D) has 20 columns, then max of this(20) is considered as number of columns in the flat file. And header row looks like this H|deptcode123|deptNameXYZ|totalemp300|||||||||...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a flat file where rows has with different metadata. You have to use a one column flat file connection manager. With `Dt_WStr` data type and length = 4000

Use 3 consecutive `DataFlow task` using the same `Flat file destination`

First one write the header, second one the middle rows, third one the footer.

You can concatenate values from the select statment or using a `Script Component`